# Is there a way to understand what fields failed in AWS api gateway validation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

We recently enabled AWS Cloud api gateway validation on our project and I added extra message (from the info I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76656569/how-to-create-custom-error-messages-for-the-invalid-fields-in-api-gateway-using)) about what went wrong with validation.
But this extra messages are impossible to read.

We have an object with 50+ properties and when I am passing this object to API Gateway, I receive a message like this:

```
{
    "message": "Invalid request body [instance failed to match 
    exactly one schema (matched 0 out of 2), format attribute 
    \"date\" not supported]"
}
```

It is really confusing...

1. format: 'date' is correct, it is working and do not appears in the unsupported swagger 3.0 fields [api-gateway-known-issues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html). I do not understand why it appears in validation error message. If the core problem that causes schema validation to fail is resolved (which is one field that appears to be number, but in schema it is string), validation passes without the problem and the request goes on to lambda. Seems like a straight up bug...
2. How am I supposed to find what fields are missing. I know for sure that one field is supposed to be string, but it is number right now, I changed it to test stuff. I have 50 fields total in my object, it is a big json. So the only way to know which field actually failed (and why) I need to manually check all the fields in the object and compare them to schema.

This poor amount of information really messes up our QA work, they do not understand where's the bug and what is broken (and if it is really broken or not).
Overall I did not find any info about this issue in google.

This whole issue makes api gateway validation feature unusable.

Comment: Might be easier to debug if you provide the schema and some data. Just something to replicate the issue.